# Making multiple search and replace more precise in Python for lemmatizer

Tags: python, regex, search, dictionary, replace

I am trying to make my own lemmatizer for Spanish in `Python2.7` using a lemmatization dictionary.

I would like to replace all of the words in a certain text with their lemma form. This is the code that I have been working on so far.

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text


my_text = 'Flojo y cargantes. Decepcionantes. Decenté decentó'
my_text_lower= my_text.lower()

lemmatize_list = 'ExampleDictionary'
lemmatize_word_dict = {}
with open(lemmatize_list) as f:
    for line in f:
        depurated_line = line.rstrip()
        (val, key) = depurated_line.split("\t")
        lemmatize_word_dict[key] = val

txt = replace_all(my_text_lower, lemmatize_word_dict)
print txt
```

Here is an example `dictionary` file which contains the lemmatized forms used to replace the words in the `input`, or `my_tyext_lower`. The example dictionary is a tab-separated 2-column file in which Col. 1 Represented the values and Col 2 represents the keys to match.

**ExampleDictionary**

```
flojo   floja
flojo   flojas
flojo   flojos
cargamento  cargamentos
cargante    cargantes
decepción   decepciones
decepcionante   decepcionantes
decentar    decenté
decentar    decentéis
decentar    decentemos
decentar    decentó
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
flojo y cargante. decepcionante. decentar decentar
```

Using these inputs (and the example phrase, as listed in `my_text`within the code). My actual output currently is:

```
felitrojo y cargramarramarrartserargramarramarrunirdo. decepáginacionarrtícolitroargramarramarrunirdo. decentar decentar
```

Currently, I can't seem to understand what it going wrong with the code.

It seems that it is replacing letters or chunks of each word, instead of recognizing the word, finding it in the `lemma dictionary` and then replace that instead.

For instance, this is the result that I am getting when I use the entire dictionary (more than 50.000 entries). This problem does not happen with my small example dictionary. Only when I use the complete dictionary which makes me think that prehaps it is double "replacing" at some point?

Is there a pythonic technique that I am missing and can incorporate into this code to make my search and replace function more precise, to identify the full words for replacement rather than chunks and/or NOT make any double replacements?

Comment: When I run your example, I get your desired output. However, there could be a problem in case one of the words contains another words from the dict.

Comment: This is the issue. There are words that will defintiely contain parts of smaller words, for instance, in the dictionary. This is why I need to try to make the "search/replace" for a whole word, rather than a word particle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use text.replace there's a chance that you'll still be matching a sub-string, and the text will get processed again.  It's better to process one input word at a time and build the output string word-by-word.

I've switched your key-value the other way around (because you want to look up the right and find the word on the left), and I mainly changed the replace_all:

```
import re

def replace_all(text, dic):
    result = ""
    input = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", text)
    for word in input:
        changed = dic.get(word,word)
        result = result + " " + changed
    return result

my_text = 'Flojo y cargantes. Decepcionantes. Decenté decentó'
my_text_lower= my_text.lower()

lemmatize_list = 'ExampleDictionary'
lemmatize_word_dict = {}
with open(lemmatize_list) as f:
    for line in f:
        kv = line.split()
        lemmatize_word_dict[kv[1]] =kv[0]

    txt = replace_all(my_text_lower, lemmatize_word_dict)
    print txt
```

Comment: I just tried out your example and I am still having problems with the words with special characters using Python2.7. Using this solution my result is: ` flojo y cargante . decepcionante . decent decent` instead of  flojo y cargante . decepcionante . decentar decentar`.

Comment: ETA. I have tried this solution by hard-coding in the regular expressions the accented leters (i.e. `input = re.findall(r"[\wáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚüÜñÑçÇ']+|[.,!?;]", text)`) and it seems to work. Just don't know if this is the best method to achieve that result.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with your code:

- it will also replace words if they appear as part of a bigger word
- by replacing words one after the other, you could replace (parts of) words that have already been replaced

Instead of that loop, I suggest using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with word boundaries `\b` to make sure that you replace complete words only. This way, you can also pass a callable as a replacement function.

```
import re
def replace_all(text, dic):
    return re.sub(r"\b\w+\b", lambda m: dic.get(m.group(), m.group()), text)
```

Comment: This solution seems to work for words with regular characters, but not for words with special characters. For instance, when testing it. The result that I obtained was `flojo y cargante. decepcionante. decenté decentó`, instead of the desired `flojo y cargante. decepcionante. decentar decentar`

Comment: @owwoow14 Hm, it works with Python 3... maybe some encoding problem?

Comment: Oops. I am using Python 2.7 I will edit my question to specify.